# Jquery: Binding change to multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, binding

For a little bit of background, I have multiple checkboxes, each weighted with a different "score". When the checkbox is changed, I need to compute the score. I thought something like the following would work but it does not look like the .change event is being bound properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   bindSomeCheckboxes();
});

function bindSomeCheckboxes() {
    var score=0;
    var checkboxes = {
        "id_1" : 3,
        "id_2" : 1,
        "id_3" : 2,
        "id_4" : 5
    };

    $.each(checkboxes, function(key, value) {
        $("#"+key).change(function(key,value) {
            if ($("#"+key).is(':checked')) {
                //add this ids value to score
            } else {
                //subtract value from score
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I know that it is looping through the array correctly, but an alert in .change is never being seen.

Comment: It should be `:checked` instead of `:clicked`, see my answer for more info.

Comment: It seems that all answers are missing the fact that each id has a unique "score". Which is why I have the mapping of id -> score. I made the clicked -> checked correction above and changed the comments to show what I am trying to accomplish. I will admit that I could be going about this all wrong. ;)

Comment: I added an answer that keeps the basic structure you were working with. I think you were trying to reference `key` inside the handler thinking it would have the ID. The trouble was that you gave your handler its own `key` parameter, which is actually referring to the `event` object. Remove (or rename) that, and you'd have the `key`. But you don't need it, because you have a direct reference to the ID you need because `this` references the one that received the event, so `this.id` is the ID of that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really wanted to take that approach of using IDs, I'd make a separate Array of the ID's, and do a `.join()` to create the selector.

Some things to note:

- Instead of `.is(':clicked')` or `.is(':checked')`, use `this.checked`. Much more efficient.
- Event handlers in jQuery have one parameter that refers to the `event`. You have 2 for `key,value`. This is making `key` in the handler refer to that `event` object instead of the `key` from the `$.each()`.
- Inside a handler, `this` refers to the one that was clicked.
- Because you have `this` reference to the element, you don't need the reference to `key` in the `$.each()`. You can just do `this.id`.

---

```
function bindSomeCheckboxes() {
    var score=0;
    var checkboxes = {
        "id_1" : 3,
        "id_2" : 1,
        "id_3" : 2,
        "id_4" : 5
    };

    var arrayOfIds = []; // to store array of ids

    $.each(checkboxes,function(key, val) {  // populate array with ids
        arrayOfIds.push( key );
    });

       // create a selector of the IDs
    $( "#" + arrayOfIds.join(',#') ).change(function() {
          // alert the score
        alert( checkboxes[ this.id ] );
        if ( this.checked ) {
            //do something when it is checked
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. An explanation of my misunderstanding of what was going on and a possible solution. +1 :)

Comment: @Magic - You're welcome. Let me know if you have any questions. :o)

Comment: Heh after all this I just realized that this isn't working partly because the div containing these checkboxes is not available on $(document).ready... Good times debugging the wrong things.

Comment: @Magic - Ah yes, that would make a difference. :o)

Answer (score 10):

I recommend you to add a container and select all checkboxes at once.

And as for your question, the signature of the event is wrong, the correct is `function(e){}`. Also, you have to check if the element is checked, and not clicked.

```
$("#chk").change(function(e){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert("checked");
    else
        alert("not checked");
});
```

To make it easier, use a container

Sample HTML

```
<div id="checks">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" />
</div>
```

And for the scores, I prefer to set data on the elements, example:

```
$("#chk1").data("Score", 3);
$("#chk2").data("Score", 1);
$("#chk3").data("Score", 2);
$("#chk4").data("Score", 5);

$("#checks :checkbox").change(function(e){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert("checked Score: " + $(this).data("Score"));
    else
        alert("not checked Score: " + $(this).data("Score"));
});
```

- **[See this example on jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/n6cmg/1/)**
- [jQuery change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I like this approach as well. Thanks for something different Bruno.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend obtaining the checkboxes in a more natural way...

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () { 
    alert("Event is bound");
});
```

If you want to restrict which checkboxes to use, you could add a class, although if you can avoid adding unnecessary classes, your html will be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

try use 'bind' and ':checked'

```
$.each(checkboxes, function(key, value) {
    $(this).bind('change', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //do something when it is checked
      } else {
        //do something else
      }
    });
});
```