# BuildIng an SQL statement with checkboxes Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

Similar questions have been asked, but I can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.  Being new to programming doesn't help either, so forgive my ignorance.

I need to build a query with the following checkboxes. Say my base SQL string is `SELECT * FROM table1`.  I want to add a WHERE clause involving the following checkboxes, depending on whether or not a checkbox is checked.

`<input type="checkbox" id = "AZ"/> Arizona</li>

<input type="checkbox" id = "CA" /> California </li>`

So if the top checkbox is checked, for example, it would turn the SQL statement into `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'AZ'`.  If neither are checked, then the SQL string remains `SELECT * FROM table1`.

`<input type="checkbox" id = "single"/> Single</li>

<input type="checkbox" id = "double" /> Double </li>`

Then, if one of the next group of checkboxes is selected, it adds further to the query.  For example, `'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'AZ' AND type='single'`.

Of course, I have many more checkbox selections, making the ultimate goal a bit lengthier, but this is the gist of it.

Most answers on this involve PHP, which I have no experience with. Is there a straight javascript/jQuery solution to this?

Comment: are you trying to build a SQL query on the client side ??? just dont!!!

Comment: This has injection written all over it.

Comment: Can you guys point me in some direction as to how I should go about it?

Comment: [Check this out to get an idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924809/jquery-binding-change-to-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: Do your have your code set up -i.e. can you get to the point where you've built an app that has some checkboxes, and can submit static SQL to a database and get a response? If not you need to take a step back and work how you are going to do this. Is this reading out of a MySQL database?

Comment: Hey ElectricLlama, I do have my code all set up, and my application is running.  I'm using CartoDB's SQL API to retrieve map layers for a web map.  I just can't figure out how to build a query based on what a user selects in the checkboxes. I realize I tagged MySQL, which I shouldn't have, so I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not talk SQL.

Typically JavaScript will send data to a server and the server will construct an SQL string and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

"Being new to programming doesn't help either, so forgive my ignorance."
You are trying too do WAY to much at one time if you're new at programing. A webpage with a JavaScript form can't (at least shouldn't) update a database. My suggestion to you is use PHP instead of JavaScript, besides: as you pointed out there's a lot of information covering how to do this in PHP :)

Comment: Thanks, seems as if I need to find myself a PHP crash course.